# How to solve Stieltjes integrals?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I am confused on how to solve Stieltjes integrals because the $dx$ part in the integrals normally becomes $dg(x)$.

For example, I have the solution to this but I just have a question about it:
let $g(x)=[x]$, the greatest integer $n$ such that $n \le x$. Evaluate the Stieltjes integral 
$$\int_0^3 g(x)d\sqrt{1+x^2}$$
after a few steps I end up at 
$$\int_1^2 d\sqrt{1+x^2} + 2\int_2^3 d\sqrt{1+x^2}$$
then in the solution the next step shows
$$\sqrt{1+x^2} |_1^2 + 2(\sqrt{1+x^2} |_2^3)$$

My **question**:

> why is the integral of $d\sqrt{1+x^2}$ simply equal to $\sqrt{1+x^2}$?

Comment: Lol Jon Snow, I mean, idknuttin, you accepted my answer in the middle of editing :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a generalisation of the Riemann integral:

Before we had:

$$\int_a^b dx = x|_a^b$$

Now we have

$$\int_a^b d(g(x)) = g(x)|_a^b$$

$\int_a^b d(g(x))$ is somewhat like $\int_a^b g'(x) dx$, much like in probability:

If we have a continuous random variable $X$ in $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$, then

$$P(X \le x) = \int_{-\infty}^x dF_X(x) \tag{*}$$

If $X$ has a pdf, then we have

$$P(X \le x) = \int_{-\infty}^x F_X'(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^x f_X(x) dx$$

Not all continuous random variables have pdfs so we can use $(*)$.

Same with [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Application_to_probability_theory): Let $g$ be a Borel-measurable function. Then

$$E[g(X)] = \int_{\mathbb R} g(x) dF_X(x)$$

If $X$ has a pdf, then we have

$$E[g(X)] = \int_{\mathbb R} g(x) F_X'(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb R} g(x) f_X(x) dx$$

Answer (score 2):

When $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$,
$$
\int_a^b\ df(x)=\int_a^b f'(x)\ dx=f(b)-f(a).
$$

See more information about the relationship between Riemann Stieltjes integrals and Riemann integrals [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Properties_and_relation_to_the_Riemann_integral).

Answer (score 0):

Owing to the uncertain integrals property
$$\int dF(x) = F(x) + const$$